# Number of categories not equal to a specific one

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a data frame with many categorical columns.
I would like to count the number of distinct categories not equal to "bla".
So for example:

```
> d1
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    x      y    
  <chr>  <chr>
1 yellow A    
2 green  A    
3 green  bla  
4 blue   B    
5 bla    bla
```

How can I modify dplyr's

```
d1 %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)
```

to exclude the category "bla"? In this case, the answer should be 3 for column `x` and 2 for column `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *base::lengths()*:

```
lengths(lapply(d1, function(i) unique(i[ i != "bla" ])))
# x y 
# 3 2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `filter_all` to `filter` the rows from all the columns and then use `n_distinct` to get length of unique values.

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
   filter_all(all_vars(. != "bla")) %>% 
    summarise_all(n_distinct)

#  x y
#1 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data table

```
library(data.table)

d1 <- data.table(d1)

d1[!y %like% 'bla', .(count = .N, distinct = uniqueN(x)), by = .(y)]
```